# Remove data frames with zero rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have more than 57 data frames, some of them have zero rows. How do I remove these?

I tried the code below

```
test=ls()    
rm(dim(test[1]==0))
```

and got an error

```
Error in rm(dim(test[1] == 0)) : 
  ... must contain names or character strings
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can create a function `isEmpty()` that returns a logical value based on a given definition of what an "empty" data frame is.  Here I assume zero columns as well, and do the dimension sums to zero.  But before that, we can save time by determining if `x` is even a data frame or not. Then we can use `eapply()` to apply our function over an environment.  Finally, just gather the names and remove as usual.

```
## create a function that returns a logical value
isEmpty <- function(x) {
    is.data.frame(x) && sum(dim(x)) == 0L
}
## apply it over the environment
empty <- unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, isEmpty))
## remove the empties
rm(list = names(empty)[empty])
```

**Note 1:** Alternatively, `isEmpty()` could possibly be

```
isEmpty <- function(x) identical(x, data.frame())
```

**Note 2:**  If you are only interested data frames with zero rows, and are allowing columns, then change `sum(dim(x)) == 0L` to `nrow(x) == 0L` in the function above.

**Note 3:**  This answer assumes all 57 data frames are in the global environment.  If they are in a list (which is recommended), then change `eapply()` to `lapply()` and `X` to your list.

Comment: `eapply`?? what on earth is this witchcraft?

Comment: Hello All 
I have tried all the below methods and i figured it out where the problem is 

> a <- data.frame()
> b <- data.frame(1:4, 5:8)
> test=ls()
> test[1]
[1] "a"
> test[2]
[1] "b"
> dim(test[1])
NULL
> dim(test[2])
NULL

Unable to find the dim(test[2])

Is there was to get the dim

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan - With that call you are actually asking for `dim("a")`, which is NULL because a character vector has no dimension.  You would have to do `dim(get(test[1]))`

Comment: I tried with get () able to get data 
But if i put it in rm() i am getting any error 

if(sum(dim(get(test[1]))==0)){rm(get(test[1]))}
Error in rm(get(test[1])) : ... must contain names or character strings

if statement run correctly but rm() does not

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `rm(list=)` to avoid this error.

This code should work:

```
test=ls()
rm(list=test[sapply(test,function(x) {
    d <- dim(get(x)); 
    length(d)==2 && sum(d)==0
    })])
```

It removes the objects that have both:

- their number of dimension that is 2
- and each of its dimension is 0

Note that this is not a good condition for `data.frame`s with 0 rows:

```
dim( data.frame(a=c(1), b=c(2))[0] )
[1] 1 0
```

It might be safer to use:

```
 rm(list=test[sapply(test,function(x) class(get(x))=="data.frame" && length(get(x))==0)])
```

Where

- `class()` is `data.frame` and
- `length()` is 0

Answer (score 0):

its time say Wooo Wooo

Here is the solution

a <- data.frame()
b <- data.frame(1:4, 5:8)

> test=ls()
>   for (j in test){if(sum(dim(get(j))==0)){rm(list=j)}}

Its Work's

Instead of using get() in rm() I pushed it the data frame into list

Answer (score -1):

You should provide some data-set to work with, but without one here is an example:

Make up some data

```
a <- data.frame()
b <- data.frame(1:4, 5:8)
```

Get your test for the existing df's

```
test <- ls()
```

What will a known empty df give you? 0,0.

```
#> dim(a)
[1] 0 0
```

So you can test for when the nrow = 0. You need to convert the character stored in test into the actual variable

```
rm(dim(eval(parse(text = test[1])))[1] == 0)
```

The above works by using

```
eval(parse(text = test[1]))
```

Which evaluates the character as the name of a variable.

You can check test[1] to test[i] or write an apply function to go over the test character.